Is 百歳 read as ひゃくさい or ももとせ?
When saying that someone/something is 100 years old, is 百歳 read as ひゃくさい or ももとせ?
I've Googled around and couldn't find a definitive answer for this. Some language sites use ひゃくさい while others use ももとせ.
(Perhaps similarly, is 千歳 read as せんさい or ちとせ?)
Thanks!

I think it will depend on context, as one seems to be the Sino-Japanese (Chinese) reading, whereas the other one is the Japanese reading.

The word 百歳 is normally read as ひゃくさい. ももとせ is how you can read this word based on the old counting system, but it's rare and you won't see it outside contexts related to history, lore or poetry. For example, biwa hōshi might prefer ももとせ, but their songs are hard to understand even to native speakers.
EDIT: Also note that when the ももとせ reading is deliberatively employed in literary works, it probably vaguely refers to "many/countless years" rather than strictly "100 years". The same is true for 千歳【ちとせ】, 千代【ちよ】, 八千代【やちよ】, etc.
See also:

Are there native Japanese numbers greater than 10? What use are they?
Why is 二十歳 pronounced はたち?


I appreciate the linked questions.  I hadn't realized they were there.  Very fascinating.

答えようと思ってたんですが、「ももとせ」って聞いたことないんで、途中で自身なくしてやめときました。辞書で引いたところ、「百歳」を「ももとせ」と読むときは「長い年月の意」な気がしてたんですが、参考に意見頂けますか？あと、「千歳」を人名以外で見たこともないんですが、こちらについても一言頂ければ嬉しいです。

@GuiImamura 仰る通り、今敢えてこの読みを使う場合は比喩的に「長い年月」の意味であることが殆どだろうとは思います。一方で最初からそうだったわけでもなく、大昔の人は文字通りの「100歳」とか「1000歳」の意味で「ももとせ」「ちとせ」と言ってたんじゃないですかね…想像ですけど。

ありがとうございます、先輩m(_)m
